# Auto adjust column widths of display:block table rows?

Tags: css, html-table

I would like to use `display: block;` for `<tr>` tags, to style margins properly.  Unfortunately, the the column widths won't be auto adjusted anymore.

Here is [a minimal example](http://jsfiddle.net/42na4/2/). The margin is ignored.

How can I use margins of table rows properly while still having auto adjusted columns?

Comment: Please provide an online demo to demonstrate the issue in action. No need to change the default display type of the table rows.

Comment: I was under this assumption that you want to apply `margin` on `<tr>` elements because of `How can I use margins of table rows properly` But you noted: `As I said, I'd like to have a padding around my table`. I think it's better to edit the question to indicate the issue better. I respectfully deleted my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`tr` tag has a default property of `display: table-row;`, by changing it to `display: block;` you are changing its default behavior intended by the browser.

Ref: http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/tr.html

You can still apply border styles to the `tr` but you will need to apply the padding to the table cells.

Based on your comments, if you want to have a margin around the table, since margin is not applicable to the tables, you can enclose the table in another element, like a `div`, and apply padding to that `div`.

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/42na4/5/

Comment: I want to apply padding around the whole table. What I tried was to add padding to the `<table>` or margin to the `<tr>`s but neither worked. Sorry, the question was misleading a bit, I updated that.

Comment: Looks good except that the table is too wide now, because it has both `width: 100%;` and some margin. There is no `box-sizing: margin-box;` to fix that.

Comment: @danijar You are welcome! glad to be of help to you.